# KOMA-Script: Table of Contents in Two Columns

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, two-column, tocbasic

I have a document in two column mode. All works fine (all in two columns) -- except the table of contents (toc). Strangely I found a solution:

```
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}
```

> This leads to a toc in two columns?! I do not understand since it says
> literally `onecolumn` in the command.

[image] (screenshot; taken from the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script))

```
\documentclass[
    twoside = false,
    twocolumn = true,
    listof=totoc,
    ]{scrbook}

% Comment in/out to see effect
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
Test

\section{Section}
Test

\subsection{SubSection}
Test

\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
Test

\paragraph{Paragraph}
Test

\subparagraph{SubParagraph}
Test

\end{document}
```

### `\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}` active

[image]

### `\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}` NOT active

[image]

## After the Solution

Be aware that there is a **`UNset` (`unsettoc`)** command and **`set` (`setuptoc`)** command. I didn't read carefully enough!

Comment: I think that `\unsettoc` switches an option off. So by default the option `onecolumn` seems to be set and by `\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}` you switch it off.

Comment: @Christian Maybe you are right - but I do not think that this is intuitive.

Comment: So, where is the question here? You might want to edit for clarity. If asking "how does the `unsettoc` command work to influence toc columns in the Koma class that should be explicitly asked.  Might also put something to that effect in the title.

Comment: @AFeldman Am I using the proper command or is this a lucky coincidence? (in addition the listof=totoc smmes not to work)

Comment: Then ask that question explicitly. In your question of course, not just here in the comments.

Comment: @AFeldman I also asked it in the question but in the end. I want to leave the question (even unanswered) since it includes the (for me unsatisfying) solution. I will ask a new question about the totoc problem if I do not figure it out the next hours.

Comment: I still don't see a question in the question, but an observation.  I certainly get your drift though from chatting here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the command `\setuptoc{<extension>}{<feature list>}` sets the features for an file extension like `toc` or `lof`, the command `\unsettoc{<extension>}{<feature list>}` unsets the listed features. Note that these are `tocbasic` commands and the file extension must be controlled by package `tocbasic`.

Each of the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook` loads package `tocbasic` and their ToC and the default lists are controlled by `tocbasic` automatically. `scrreprt` and `scrbook` also set the feature `onecolumn` for the TOC and the lists of owner `float` as default. So if you do not want a onecolumn TOC with `scrreprt` or `scrbook` you have to use

```
\unset{toc}{onecolumn}
```

to deactivate the `onecolumn` feature for the TOC.

If the lists (controlled by `tocbasic`) should alse be twocolumn, you can use

```
\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile{\unsettoc{\@currext}{onecolumn}}
\makeatother
```

`listof=totoc` is an option of the KOMA-Script classes which does the same as

```
\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile[float]{\setuptoc{\@currext}{totoc}}
\makeatother
```

So it effects only lists of the owner `float` like `lof` or `lot` and *not* `toc`. Note that an entry of the TOC in the TOC is not recommended. But it is possible with

```
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
```

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
    twoside = false,
    twocolumn = true,
    listof=totoc,
    ]{scrbook}

\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}

\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile{\unsettoc{\@currext}{onecolumn}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Chapter}
Test
\section{Section}
Test
\subsection{SubSection}
Test
\subsubsection{SubSubSection}
Test
\paragraph{Paragraph}
Test
\subparagraph{SubParagraph}
Test
\captionof{figure}{A Figure}
\end{document}
```