# Troubles with an article in two columns with KOMA Script

Tags: koma-script, two-column, languages, abstract, scrartcl

I'm working on an article in KOMA Script, the idea is to have it in double column, but I'm having some problems that I can't solve:

1. I have 2 abstracts in different languages, if I deactivate the `titlepage` option, they appear on the same page but when I activate the `titlepage` option each one appears centred on a different page.
2. The table of contents appears on a single page but from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318640/koma-script-table-of-contents-in-two-columns), I have corrected it.

Problem 1 is the one I can't solve yet, when I activate the two columns option and deactivate the title page the table of contents appears on the same page but it would look better to have one in each column, is there a way to force a column break in KOMA?

Another doubt I have is if inside KOMA using the two-column option there is a way to balance the columns at the end of the document?

Finally, the default gutter in KOMA Script is too narrow and makes the columns look too close together, is there a way to adjust that with `typearea`, for example?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{%
    fontsize=11pt,%
    headings=big,%
    headsepline=on,%
    titlepage=on,%
    paper=b5,%
    DIV=calc,%
    twoside=on,%
    BCOR=5mm,%
    parskip=half+,% 
    abstract=on,
    twocolumn=on,
    bibliography=totoc 
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[math,toc]{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
    linefill=\quad,%
    raggedpagenumber,%
    pagenumberbox=\hbox% 
   ]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}
\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=1000 

\titlehead{Contemporary Science Journal}
\subject{(Peer-reviewed paper)}
\title{Paper title:}
\subtitle{Paper subtitle}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\publishers{Some Academic Press}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
 {\small
  \selectlanguage{Spanish}
  \begin{abstract}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \smallskip
    \textbf{Descriptores:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
  \end{abstract}
  { 
  \selectlanguage{English}
  \begin{abstract}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \smallskip
    \textbf{Keywords:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
  \end{abstract} 
  }
}
  \newpage
  \tableofcontents
  \blinddocument
  \blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

One last detail that I forgot, I notice that when I activate the `twocolumn` option the footer disappears, which is where I usually place the page number.

Comment: I don't know if this is expected behavior, but I can confirm it. The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to replace the `abstract` environments with `\section*{Resumen}` and `\section*{Abstract}`: That way, they are treated like regular sections, but are not added to the TOC.

Comment: It is an option but generally, the abstract is composed in smaller font size and the title is usually centred, which is a different format than a section with or without a number. 

Besides, you are supposed to activate the `abstract` option and use the `abstract` environment, which makes it easier for you to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the abstract page you could change option `titlepage` to `off`:

```latex
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=off}% <- added
{\small
  \selectlanguage{Spanish}
  \begin{abstract}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \smallskip
    \textbf{Descriptores:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
  \end{abstract}
  \newpage% <- added
  {%
    \selectlanguage{English}
    \begin{abstract}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

      \smallskip
      \textbf{Keywords:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
    \end{abstract}
  }
}
\clearpage% <- added
```

Or you could remove the `abstract` environment and use `\addsec*{\abstractname}`.

```latex
{\small
  \selectlanguage{Spanish}
  \addsec*{\abstractname}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \smallskip
    \textbf{Descriptores:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
  \newpage% <- added
  {%
    \selectlanguage{English}
    \addsec*{\abstractname}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \smallskip
    \textbf{Keywords:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
  }
}
\clearpage% <- added
```

I have added a `\newpage` after the first abstract. So the second abstract starts in a new column.

To solve the footer issue, you can add option `includefoot=on` (or `includehead=off` after `headsepline=on`).

You can try package `flushend` to balance the columns of the last page.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %fontsize=11pt,% default
  headsepline=on,% sets headinclude=on automatically
  footinclude=on,% <- added
  paper=b5,%
  %DIV=calc,% default for paper≠a4
  twoside=on,%
  BCOR=5mm,%
  parskip=half+,% 
  twocolumn=on
]{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{%
  %headings=big,% default
  titlepage=on,%
  %abstract=on,
  bibliography=totoc 
}

\usepackage{flushend}% <- added

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed for outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}% only for dummy text

%\usepackage{tocbasic}% <- loaded by the class!
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
  linefill=\quad,%
  raggedpagenumber,%
  pagenumberbox=\mbox% 
 ]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}
\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}

\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=1000 

\titlehead{Contemporary Science Journal}
\subject{(Peer-reviewed paper)}
\title{Paper title:}
\subtitle{Paper subtitle}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\publishers{Some Academic Press}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% abstract
\KOMAoptions{titlepage=off}% <- added
{\small
  \selectlanguage{Spanish}
  \begin{abstract}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    \smallskip
    \textbf{Descriptores:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
  \end{abstract}
  \newpage% <- added
  {%
    \selectlanguage{English}
    \begin{abstract}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

      \smallskip
      \textbf{Keywords:} blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
    \end{abstract}
  }
}
\clearpage% <- added

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]